# Select inside function not working as expected

Tags: function, select, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a function to encapsulate a select on PL/SQL.

But the result I get from using the function is different that the one I get from using the select on it's own.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fecha_ultimo_trasiego(fermentacion IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN DATE
IS fecha DATE;
BEGIN 
    SELECT (
        SELECT fecha
        FROM (
            SELECT t.id, t.fecha
            FROM TrasiegoAux t
            WHERE t.fermentacion=fermentacion 
            ORDER BY t.fecha desc
        )
        WHERE ROWNUM=1
    ) INTO fecha FROM DUAL;
    RETURN(fecha); 
END;
```

Is there something wrong on the declaration of my function? Right now it always returns the same value no matter what parameter it gets as input.

The expected output is the date of the last Trasiego (the max date of the table).

This is my structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Fermentacion(
    id VARCHAR2(36)
);

CREATE TABLE Trasiego(
    id VARCHAR2(36),
    fecha DATE not null,
    fermentacion VARCHAR2(36) REFERENCES Fermentacion,
    temperatura NUMBER(8) not null,
    litrosFinal NUMBER(8) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, fermentacion)
);

create or replace view TrasiegoAux as select id, fecha, fermentacion from Trasiego;
```

Here is some data:

```
Insert into FERMENTACION (ID) values ('4');
Insert into FERMENTACION (ID) values ('9');

Insert into TRASIEGO (ID,FERMENTACION,TEMPERATURA,LITROSFINAL,FECHA) values ('1','4',20,190,to_date('04-OCT-16','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into TRASIEGO (ID,FERMENTACION,TEMPERATURA,LITROSFINAL,EMPLEADOLABORATORIO,FECHA) values ('2','4',20,180,to_date('11-OCT-16','DD-MON-RR'));
Insert into TRASIEGO (ID,FERMENTACION,TEMPERATURA,LITROSFINAL,FECHA) values ('3','9',20,190,to_date('04-OCT-16','DD-MON-RR'));
```

Given that data I would expect that this:

```
DECLARE  
fecha date;
BEGIN
  fecha :=fecha_ultimo_trasiego(4);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fecha); //'11-OCT-16'
  fecha :=fecha_ultimo_trasiego(4);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fecha); //'04-OCT-16'
END;
```

Comment: Whats the expected output

Comment: Please show sample table data, and how the function is called, and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely to be because you're passing in the parameter with the same name as the column. That's not a good idea, as it causes all sorts of strangeness.

You can either amend the parameter name, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fecha_ultimo_trasiego(p_fermentacion IN VARCHAR2) 
...
    WHERE t.fermentacion = p_fermentacion
...
```

or you could qualify the parameter name in the query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fecha_ultimo_trasiego(fermentacion IN VARCHAR2) 
...
    WHERE t.fermentacion = fecha_ultimo_trasiego.fermentacion
...
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 1 minute :(

Comment: \*holds out wrist so it can be slapped\* \*{;-)

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. I will accept the anwser as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the parameter a different name to any of the columns in TrasiegoAux, or else prefix it with the function name, e.g.

```
WHERE t.fermentacion = fecha_ultimo_trasiego.fermentacion
```

or else (after renaming the parameter):

```
WHERE t.fermentacion = p_fermentacion
```

Edit: Boneist beat me to it.

You could probably simplify the code a bit, though, as the `select ... from dual` wrapper doesn't seem to be needed:

```
create or replace function fecha_ultimo_trasiego
    ( p_fermentacion in trasiegoaux.fermentacion%type )
    return date
as
    l_fecha date;
begin
    select fecha into l_fecha
    from   ( select t.fecha
             from   trasiegoaux t
             where  t.fermentacion = p_fermentacion
             order  by t.fecha desc )
    where  rownum = 1;

    return l_fecha;
end;
```